# Error while trying to compile program for Android in Processing for first time

Tags: java, android, processing

I'm sure this must be easy to solve, but I haven't been able to do it. I already have the AndroidMode active, but when I click the run button in a simple program I get this:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/ivanarevalo/Desktop/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:

/Users/ivanarevalo/Desktop/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

Thank you for your help!

I'm using processing **2.2.1**!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Just needed the last version of AndroidMode, you can find it in the processing GitHub.